# knockout.js create new record with data after clicking a button

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I would like to fill two input fields, then "submit" them clicking a button, and have them displayed in newly created row of a table. Is something like this possible with knockout? If so, how can I achieve it?

```
<p>First name: <input data-bind="value: firstName" /></p>
<p>Last name: <input data-bind="value: lastName" /></p>

<a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"  role="button"  >Add</a>

<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class=panel-heading>Your data</div>
    <table class=table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>First name</th>
                <th>Last name</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you probably want is an [observable array](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html). It works just like the other observables you have but can contain many objects.

Combine that with the [`foreach`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html) binding and you've got a recipe for filling out a table.

```js
var AppViewModel = function() {
  this.firstName = ko.observable();
  this.lastName = ko.observable();
  this.records = ko.observableArray();
};
var model = new AppViewModel();

$('.btn').click(function() {
  // Create a record on click
  model.records.push({ 
    firstName: model.firstName(),
    lastName: model.lastName()
  });
});

ko.applyBindings(model);
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<p>First name: <input data-bind="value: firstName" /></p>
<p>Last name: <input data-bind="value: lastName" /></p>

<a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"  role="button"  >Add</a>

<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class=panel-heading>Your data</div>
    <table class=table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>First name</th>
                <th>Last name</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: records">
          <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: firstName"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: lastName"></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

If you aren't using jQuery, you can setup the click binding using normal event listeners.

```
document.querySelector('.btn').addEventListener('click', function() {
  model.records.push({
    firstName: model.firstName(),
    lastName: model.lastName()
  });
});
```

Even better than that, you can use what Denis Pitcher said and give the model a method which you apply using `data-bind="click: add()"`.

Comment: Wouldn't putting a jquery click event on the 'btn' class cause all elements with that class to have the click event fired?  A click knockout binding would be more appropriate.

Comment: @DenisPitcher It would but for the sample code here it suffices. In general, I agree that using a knockout click event as you have shown is more appropriate.

Comment: How did you add the code run code snippet buttons?  I've just started seeing those and they're awesome.  You definitely beat me on a more thorough answer :)  It tends to be why I never answer questions on stack overflow, because by the time I've got a decent answer together someone else has beaten me to it, heh.

Comment: @DenisPitcher Haha, thanks! When you're writing your answer, look at the buttons along the top and you'll find what looks like a piece of paper with `<>` on it. Click that and you can edit a runnable code snippet.

Comment: Thats awesome, they built in a fiddler.  Thanks a ton for letting me know, not sure if I'd ever have noticed that button

Answer (score 3):

Use an observable array as your binding
http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html

Add a data binding to your link

```
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"  role="button" data-bind="click: add()" >Add</a>
```

Assuming you've defined your viewmodel as vm, do the following:

add an oberservable array to your view model

```
vm.myarray = ko.observableArray();
```

Add a function to your view model

```
vm.add = function() {
    vm.myarray.push({firstName: firstName, lastName: lastName };

}
```

Add a binding to your table row

```
<tr data-bind="foreach: myarray">
    <th data-bind="text: firstName"></th>
    <th data-bind="text: lastName"></th>
</tr>
```